# Insert Statement into Azure SQL Table is not possible because of NullException

Tags: sql, nullpointerexception, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

i've searched for cases under similiar conditions, but can't find something like my problem.

I would like to add a simple Insert into my Table Seats

```
    package com.mergim;

    //Use the JDBC driver
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class SQLTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection();
 }
 public static void Connection() throws SQLException{
     String connectionString =
             "jdbc:sqlserver://eebproject.database.windows.net:1433;"+"ssl=require;"
             + "database=MYDATABASE;"
             + "user=MYNAME;"
             + "password=MYPASSWORD;"
             + "encrypt=true;"
             + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
             +"hostNameInCertificate=northeurope1a.control.database.windows.net;"
             + "loginTimeout=30;";

     // Declare the JDBC objects.
     Connection connection = null;

     try {
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
         System.out.println("Database connected.");
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }


     String sql = "INSERT INTO Seats (seat_used) VALUES ('"+true+"')";
     PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);  
     stmt.execute();

     // SELECT ALL ENTRIES 
     Statement stmt1 = connection.createStatement();
     String sql1 = "SELECT seat_id, seat_used FROM Seats";
     ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);

     while(rs.next()){
         System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getInt(1));
         System.out.print(" --> Status: " + rs.getBoolean(1));
         System.out.println();
      }      
     rs.close();
     System.out.println("Finished SelectAll-Statement."); 
 }  
}
```

It works on localhost, but i have to deploy it on azure.
I start this Class over RESTAPI and get the following Error-Code.
I can't understand, why the code works on localhost, but not within azure.

```
    <b>message</b>
        <u></u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>exception</b>
    </p>
    <pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mergim.SQLTest.Connection(SQLTest.java:37)
com.mergim.Sitzplatzstatus.post(Sitzplatzstatus.java:49)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Why the following code is null?

```
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Seats (seat_used) VALUES ('"+true+"')";
     PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);  
     stmt.execute();
```

Comment: If you fail to get a connection with `connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);` you will get the desired NPE when trying to prepare a statement

Comment: Do you get "Database connected." on your output before the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think that you're right with the first assumption. I think my connection is null, but i can't understand why? It works on localhost, but not on my azure cloud/ azure webapp? I changed the connectionString to                 String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true";  But it  doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error and the reason was a missing path to the jdbc driver. 
The missing path to the jdbc driver had an effect on

```
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

With the correct path the code above is now working. Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

try n replace code...

```
while(rs.next()){
         System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getInt(0));
         System.out.print(" --> Status: " + rs.getBoolean(1));
         System.out.println();
      }
```

Comment: At first I'd like to thank you for your quick response. The Code below //SELECT ALL ENTRIES don't have any effect at the Nullpointer-Exception, which I can't understand. I've build this part only for testing. Nevertheless thanks for your answer.